# MongoDB WiredTiger Storage

Tags: mongodb, storage, wiredtiger

I got a issue on mongodb wiredtiger storage.What is the use of storing this in to volume(Disk).If we delete those .wt extension files it would be any impact to MongoDB database? Could you please help me on this.
Awaiting for your reply.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Those files contain necessary metadata. Deleting them will make your databases and collections unusable, from what I would guess. But *why* do you want to delete them?

Comment: Thanks for the sharing info

Comment: Avtually my root volume disk was 100 GB out of this MongoDB storage path was taken 70GB .wt extension collections soooo

Comment: I have a collection with 17GB. My storage shows 43 GB "storageSize" : 43656536064 (43 GB)

db.collectioname.stats() 

{
 "ns" : "dbname.collectioname",
 "size" : 17979330531,
 "storageSize" : 43656536064,
I removed data in collection.

My collection shows 2 MB  ( "size" : 2337254,) and storage sizde still shows 43 GB. "storageSize" : 43656536064 (43 GB). How can i reduce the storage size to a reasonable storage limit.

db.collection.stats()

{
 "ns" : "dbname.collectioname",
 "size" : 2337254,
 "storageSize" : 43656536064,